# Fix the last li of list

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-lists

I am using angular and want to fix the last `<li>` of list . I am actually doing this in notification center in which all notification will be loaded and last option is of "show all notification" which i want to fix. here i am posting html. I used some css but didn't work for me

**html**

```
<ul  id="list-wrapper-noti" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right style-3" >
   <div infinite-scroll-disabled = "disableScroll" infinite-scroll='loadMoreNotifications()' infinite-scroll-distance='0' infinite-scroll-container="'#list-wrapper-noti'">
     <div ng-repeat = "notification in notifications track by $index">
        <li>
            <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#534D4D" href="{{notification.href}}" >
               <div class="media">

              <img src="https://papa.fit/routes/images/inst_logo/default.png" alt="fakeimg" class="img-circle pull-left" style="height:50px; width:50px;">

              <div class="media-body">
                 <div class="media">{{notification.employee}} {{notification.action | lowercase}} {{notification.element}} {{notification.record_value}}</div>
                  <span class="muted">{{notification.time_string}}</span>
                 </div>

              </div>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>
    </div>
  </div>
   // this li should be fix 
   <li>
     <a href="list.php?id=20" style=" color:#3C71C1;"><i class="fa fa-globe pull-right"></i>Show all notifications</a>
   </li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.style-3 li:last-child {
          position: fixed;
          background-color: white;
 }
```

Comment: what do you want to fix with the last li ?

Comment: this one ...<li>
     <a href="list.php?id=20" style=" color:#3C71C1;"><i class="fa fa-globe pull-right"></i>Show all notifications</a>
   </li>

Comment: If you wanna do the last li you shouldn't use 'first' child but 'last' child, Like `style-3 li:last-child { ... } `

Comment: sorry it was a mistake @Minegolfer

Comment: I edited my question it is actually a last-child in css. thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Is the `last-child` not working?  You can try giving the li a class like `<li class = "myClass" `  and in the css `li.myClass { position: fixed;  background-color: white; } `

Comment: Given your HTML I'd suggest looking at your DOM, because you've got invalid HTML: the *only* valid child of a `<ul>` element is an `<li>`, *every* other type of element must be wrapped in an `<li>`, there are no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` tags are not valid children of an `<ul>`

Place your iterator on the `<ul>` and move your "Show all link" out of your list.

```
<ul ng-repeat="notification in notifications track by $index">
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="show-all">Show all notifications</a>
```

This should also make your styling much easier.